# How to grab certain number of characters before and after a perl regex match?

Tags: regex, perl

I am crafting regexes that match certain terms best within html code.  I'm doing this in an iterative process to whittle down matches to exclude things I don't want.  So I craft a regex, run it, and spit out data that I then look through to see how well my match is working.  For example, if I am looking for the term "tema" (the name of a trade association that provides standards) I might notice that it also matches "sitemap" and alter my regex in some way to exclude the unwanted items.

To make this easier, I want to print out my match along with some context, say 20 charcters before and after the match, rather than the entire line, to make it easier to scan through the results.  This is proving frustratingly hard to accomplish in a simple fashion.

For example, I would think this would work:

`$line =~ /(.{,20}tema.{,20})/i;`

That is, I want to match up to 20 of anything before and after my keyword and include it in the "context" I print out for scanning.

But it doesn't.  Am I missing something here?  If a{,20} will match up to 20 'a' characters, why won't .{,20} match 20 of anything that '.' will match?

Scratching my head.

Comment: What dou you mean by `it doesn't`? Do you get less characters? No characters? No match? An error? Note that `.` cannot match line breaks. Use the `s` modifier if you want to include line breaks in those arbitrary characters.

Comment: I don't think your code example is correct.

Comment: It doesn't return anything.  No match.

Comment: Whoops, yea, bad cut/paste error, I fixed it above.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

- `atom{n}` (exactly *n*)
- `atom{n,}` (*n* or more)
- `atom{n,m}` (*n* or more, but no more than *m*)

So,

```
say $1 if $line =~ /(.{0,20}tema.{0,20})/i;
```

Or if you're using `/g` and might get overlapping matches:

```
say "$1$2$3" while $line =~ /(.{0,20})\K(tema)(?=(.{0,20}))/ig;
```

(`a{,20}` doesn't "match up to 20 `a` characters.")

Comment: Beautiful thanks.  I think leaving out the zero in .{0,20} was it.  I found that syntax somewhere in a perl regex tutorial but obviously it was wrong.

Comment: @Peter C, Might have been for another language's regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

How about searching with `m/^(.*)tema(.*)$/` then use `substr` or similar to get the last characters of `$1` and the first from `$2`.

Comment: That is what I am doing now (but with $`,$&, and $' for before/match/after strings), but it is messy.  I was hoping to be able to do it all in a regex so I just have one line instead of 8.